# Perform xpath function on an xform output node

Tags: xpath, xforms

I've got an xform with an output element that references a "time" node in my model that contains a string something like "00:12:34,567".  I'd like the text of the output element to be the substring "00:12:34".  I didn't quite expect this to work but maybe you'll get what I'm trying to do.

```
<xf:output ref="substring-before(//time[1],',')">
    <xf:label>Time</xf:label>
</xf:output>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `ref` attribute pointing to an atomic value should work as per XForms 2.0, but maybe your implementation doesn't support this feature yet. So try to use the `value` attribute, which is more appropriate here anyway:

```
<xf:output value="substring-before(//time[1],',')">
    <xf:label>Time</xf:label>
</xf:output>
```